# Two instances of the same Python module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, python-internals

I created a Python module with a single function that just prints 'a!'. I opened up the Python interpreter and imported the module in 2 different syntaxes

```
>>> import a
>>> from a import func
>>> func()
a!
>>> a.func()
a!
```

At this point I changed func to print something else, then evaluates again

```
>>> func()
a!
>>> a.func()
a!
```

This is expected of course as the module was not reloaded. Then I reloaded the module and expected both functions to update, however:

```
>>> reload(a)
<module 'a' from 'a.py'>
>>> a.func()
aasd!
>>> func()
a!
```

Only a.func seems to update. I always thought that Python keeps only a single instance of the same module, but now there appears to be two. I did further testing in order to verify my claim, and added a print statement at top level of the module, then restarted the interpreter and imported again:

```
>>> import a
module imported
>>> import a
>>> from a import func
```

This confuses me even more as I expected to see 'module imported' twice. The third experiment that I did was the global variable experiment:

```
>>> import a
module imported
>>> from a import GLOBAL_VAR
>>> GLOBAL_VAR = 5
>>> a.GLOBAL_VAR
1
>>> GLOBAL_VAR
5
>>> GLOBAL_VAR is a.GLOBAL_VAR
False
```

So there's a single instance of the module, but different instances of the objects inside? How is it possible to implement [Gevent's monkey patching](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html) with such behaviour?

Comment: You took a reference to an object inside the module. And that reference keeps that object alive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A module, once it's imported, is just another python object. So seeing the following example, your results should not surprise you at all:

```
x = SomeObject()
x.y = 1
a = x.y
x.y = 2
print(a) #a is still 1, not 2
```

When you do `from module import name`, a variable `name` is created in the current namespace which holds a reference to the imported thing (be it a package/module/class/whatever). It's syntactic sugar for the following:

```
import module
name = module.name
```

Now, when you reload `module`, you obviously don't update the reference `name` holds.

Concerning your second experiment, a module is cached in `sys.modules` after the import; subsequent imports will take advantage of the cache. Thus all code that is directly at the module level, like your `print`, will only get executed on the first import.

Answer (score 3):

When you reload a module, all the functions in that are reloaded in the current module. But when you import a specific function from a module, it becomes local to the current module. So, changing one will not affect the other.

Check this out:

```
import math
from math import factorial
print locals()

print id(math.factorial), id(factorial)

math.factorial, factorial = 0, 1
print id(math.factorial), id(factorial)

reload(math)
print id(math.factorial), id(factorial)

from math import factorial
print id(math.factorial), id(factorial)
```

**Output**

```
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
 '__file__': '/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.py',
 '__package__': None,
 'factorial': <built-in function factorial>, # Factorial is in the local context
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '__doc__': None,
 'math': <module 'math' (built-in)>}
39346504 39346504
33545712 33545688
39346504 33545688
39346504 39346504
```

[`id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) prints the address of the object in memory in CPython implementation

Answer (score 0):

I thing that I just confirmed is that a particular session of Python ensures that there is only one instance of a particular module (more specifically a file path).

**Proof(single Python session used):**

*foobar.py:*

```
a = 123
def foo(): print a
```

*Python:*

```
>>> from foobar import foo
>>> foo()
123
```

*Changing foobar.py:*

```
a = 1234
def foo(): print a;print a
```

*Python:*

```
>>> reload(foobar)
<module 'foobar' from 'c:\foobar.py'>
>>> foobar.foo()
1234
1234
>>> foo()
1234
>>> id(sys.modules[foo.__module__]) == id(sys.modules[foobar.foo.__module__])
True
```

The only thing that is causing different outputs is the `code` object, (`foo.__globals['a']` and `foobar.foo.__globals__['a']` are the same)

```
>>> id(foo.__code__) == id(foobar.foo.__code__)
False
```

No idea about `Gevent` monkey patching.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, variables are names, not containers. Everything is an object, everything is a reference, while variables are neither. Variables refer to objects and namespaces map names to objects. You can use module to organize code, every module is executed on first import.

So after you import a as b, b refer to object a, a will stay the same unless you modify object a(if a is mutable). When you reload(a), you just assign one new object to a variable, that has nothing to do with b at all.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> a = 2
>>> print b
1

>>> import a
>>> from a import func
>>> id(func) 
4324575544
>>> id(a.func)
4324575544
>>> reload(a)
<module 'a' from 'a.py'>
>>> id(a.func)
4324576624
>>> id(func)
4324575544
```

Comment: If you from a import b, then you do b = 2, what you have is that a.b is object_b, b refers to object_2, of course b is not a.b

Comment: When you reload `a`, `b` also changes because reload operates of the object (`module`) `a` refers to (also referred to by `b`) and reloads it. `a`'s referent is not changed neither is `b`'s. Rest assured I have confirmed this.

Comment: I add more detail, that is what I get, whatever, if it still bothers u, just read the Python source code, you will find it out.